# image quality deteriorates when used more than once

Tags: html, image

In my html page, I include an image as

```
<img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/w2o9kh.png" border="0" alt="Image by TinyPic">
```

I style it from an external css by

```
img {width:2em;height:2em; }
```

However I notice that the image quality deteriorates when same image is used more than once in a page.
Compare http://jsfiddle.net/aJ333/50/  and http://jsfiddle.net/zxgQr/ in firefox. The quality of smiley is worse in the first one.

Any insight on why this happens and how to retain the quality ?

P.S. Ive checked this happens even if images are in different div containers.

P.S. This seems to be browser specific:
In chrome both are good quality
In IE9 both are bad quality
In firefox quality of smiley is worse in the first fiddle.
I would like this to work in firefox at least.

Im novice in html so please bear with in case this is obvious

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known bug in Firefox (and IE it seems), see bug reports: [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=486918) and follow-up [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=795072).

Comment: @pjumble thanks for the reference. Is there a know workaround that I can use in this kind of situations to retain the image quality ?  For e.g. I tried div containers to separate them but that doesnt work.

Comment: I notice that the unscaled smiley is considerably larger than you want to render it. Does it help at all if you make the size of the image on the server a bit closer to how it will be used?

Comment: Good point @Andrew Morton, I was wondering why I hadn't encountered this bug in actual use. The scaled image quality (in IE / Firefox / Opera) only seems to become an issue when you're including the image twice _and_ the source image is more than double the size you're displaying. http://jsfiddle.net/aJ333/54/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a height and a width value on your images. If those values are bigger or smaller than the actual dimensions of the picture, the browser must scale it. This process changes the resolution of the picture making it look somewhat blurry.